# Problem with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with setInterval on a 'click' event. Im already spawning a hidden div. But I want spawn and fade in synced and only run the fade in ones.

```
 var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
                var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenElement');
                var bkgFade = document.getElementById('bkgFade');

                anchor.addEventListener('click', spawnImage, false);
                hiddenElement.addEventListener('click', despawnImage, false);
                function spawnImage() {
                     setInterval(function() {
                        document.getElementById('hiddenElement').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('bkgFade').style.visibility = 'visible';
                         hiddenElement.style.opacity += 1.0;
                    } 1000);


                }

                function despawnImage() {
                    document.getElementById('hiddenElement').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('bkgFade').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
```

Comment: This might be nitpicking but what does that `F` there mean?

Comment: Can you not use a framework like jQuery? Also, you don't appear to be specifying a delay for setInterval and clearInterval should take the id of the interval as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code makes no sense to me:

```
function spawnImage() {
     setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('hiddenElement').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bkgFade').style.visibility = 'visible';
        F hiddenElement.style.opacity += 1;
    });
    clearInterval();
}
```

There are multiple things wrong with it.

1. You aren't setting a time for `setInterval()`.
2. You aren't saving the return value from `setInterval()`.
3. You aren't passing anything to `clearInterval()`.  It should be passed the return value from `setInterval()`.  It won't do anything the way you have it.
4. This line isn't legal javascript: `F hiddenElement.style.opacity += 1;`
5. I can't understand why you would `setInterval()` and then immediately `clearInterval()`
6. Adding 1 to the opacity in a timer interval isn't going to accomplish anything.  That's just going to make it visible in one giant step.
7. Manipulating `opacity` directly won't work in some versions of IE.
8. You're using `document.getElementById('hiddenElement')` in one place and `hiddenElement` in another place.  If `hiddenElement` is valid, use that both places.  If not, use `document.getElementById('hiddenElement')` both places.

If you describe in more detail what you're really trying to accomplish with this code, folks might be able to help you come up with correct code.

I would highly recommend that animation be done with a library like jQuery or YUI as it's way, way easier to use and make it work cross-browser.

Comment: Im terribly sorry. I've unfortunately sent you the wrong piece of code.
Now I have edited like it were before i tryed some diffrent techniques.
The reason why im not doin it in jQuery is becasue I'm learning javasript from the basics in a school projekt.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but my points 6, 7 and 8 are still pertinent observations.  Opacity is a decimal from 0 to 1.0, so adding 1 to it will immediately take it from 0 to 1 with no animation.

Comment: Also, waiting 18hrs to come back, check for answers and tell us you put in the wrong code doesn't inspire people to want to help you.  And, point #9 is that you set an interval timer and you never stop it.  It's going to be increasing the opacity forever.

Comment: I'm spawning a element on a 'click' event. And now I want it to fade in from 'opacity: 0;'(that i declare in the css) to opacity: 1. I will not put any care on IE:s own DOM. Instead I gonna concentrate making this to work. 

How do I brake setInterval()?

Comment: If you want the opacity to go from 0 to 1, I think you want to add something a lot less than 1 in each timer call.  Probably more like 0.01.   For the interval timer, read my points #2 and #3.  Then, read the documentation for setInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) and clearInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.clearInterval)

Comment: Thanks for the help and excuse me for the misunderstanding.